# IntelliJ generate signed APK not working

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to generate a signed APK for production, I manage to get through all steps from the menus
Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Keystore etc..

when I go to the path specified for the APK, I cannot see the file generated.

I have generated APK before, but it's been a while since I touched this project and perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once i faced same issue. I changed the apk's output path and it was fixed. I hope this'll help you.

Comment: I wish it would be that easy. I did try that too but it didn't work :(.

Comment: Hey, did anybody solve the problem? Having it right now.